# Iframe активный скролинг при poenter-events:none

Tags: html, css, html5, iframe

Есть iframe внутри которого сайт. iframe  с прокруткой (скролом) Мне нужно что бы все его содержимое было недоступно кроме скрола
использую pointer-events:none но он действует на весь iframe
В #document или в html фрэйма попасть ен получается для того что бы только им прописать поинтер эвентс
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: насколько я понимаю, вы можете получить доступ к DOM для изменения отдельных стилей только если iframe имеет тот же домен
Это сделано для избежания подмены стилей в целях безопасности
Вот похожий вопрос на ваш https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494721/override-body-style-for-content-in-an-iframe

Comment: Если речь о кроссдоменном iframe, то можно разве что попробовать предугадать длину контента и задать какое-то большое значение высоты, в сочетании c pointer-events:none. Получившуюся простыню можно разместить в контейнере с overflow:scroll